# How can I color only Cover page for PhD thesis

Tags: color, covers

Can you help me in formatting my title page (cover page). It is for my PhD thesis.
I have to follow this example https://www.dropbox.com/s/clexb8dauxom2k4/tamplate.jpg ...
For this purpose I am using these codes for title page

```
\begin{titlepage}

\pagecolor{gray}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

%Cover image
   \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{images.eps}
   \end{center}
    %Autor name
    \begin{center}
 \vspace*{2cm}
  {\LARGE\bf Gilson Manuel Gomes Pina}

    %Thesis title
      \vspace*{1.2cm}
  {\Huge \bf Monetary and Fiscal Policy and Business Cycles in Emerging Markets}


 \vspace*{1.2cm}

  {\small PhD thesis in economics, specializing in Monetary Economics, supervised by Professor Pedro Bação and Professor Ricardo Sousa and presented to the Faculty of Economics, University of Coimbra.}

    \vspace*{1.0cm}

    {\small September 2014}

    \end{center}

  \vspace*{1.6cm}

    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{insigniafeuc.eps}
        \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \textsc{\small Faculty of Economics, University of Coimbra}
    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

and for the full thesis compilation I am using:

```
\documentclass{dmathesis}
%% uncommand the following line to print equation labels next to
%% equation numbers. 
\usepackage{lipsum}% for auto generating text
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{showlabel}
%% The following is to control the format of the thesis
\input{format}

%% File to be included while running latex.
\includeonly{chapter1,chapter2,chapter3%
                 ,chapter4,chapter5,chapter6,ref,append}

\begin{document}

%% Front page of thesis
\input{coverpage}
\input{frontpage}

%% Main text
% set page number starts from 1
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%% To ensure the equation counter works correctly
\eqlabon
\eqlaboff

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{ref}
\include{append}
\end{document}
```

So, the problem are: first one, I need to include the "color page" just for cover page, but it will appear in the full thesis. I'm trying many examples from the web, but anything is working. How can I do that? And the second one, How can I put the image to occupy full top of the cover page, as in the example?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the `book` class but it should work for your class too.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newgeometry{centering,top=0in}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \pagecolor{gray}
    \afterpage{\pagecolor{white}}

    %Cover image
    \centering
    \noindent
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.4\textheight]{example-image-a}%
    }

    %Author name
    \vspace*{2cm}
    {\LARGE\bf Gilson Manuel Gomes Pina\par}

    %Thesis title
      \vspace*{1.2cm}
    {\Huge \bf Monetary and Fiscal Policy and Business Cycles in Emerging Markets \par}

    \vspace*{1.2cm}

    {\small PhD thesis in economics, specializing in Monetary Economics, supervised by Professor 
    Pedro Bação and Professor Ricardo Sousa and presented to the Faculty of Economics, University 
    of Coimbra. \par}

    \vspace*{1.0cm}

    {\small September 2014 \par}

    \vspace*{1.6cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}

    \textsc{\small Faculty of Economics, University of Coimbra}
    \par
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `dmathesis` class:

```
\documentclass{dmathesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}     %% for demo
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}   %% pass in important
\begin{document}
%% cover.tex starts--------------------------
\newgeometry{centering,top=0in}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \pagecolor{gray}
    \afterpage{\pagecolor{white}}

    %Cover image
    \centering
    \setlength{\hoffset}{0in}
    \noindent
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{example-image-a}%
    }

    %Author name
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\LARGE\bf Gilson Manuel Gomes Pina\par}

    %Thesis title
      \vspace*{0.75cm}
    {\Huge \bf Monetary and Fiscal Policy and Business Cycles in Emerging Markets \par}

    \vspace*{0.75cm}

    {\small PhD thesis in economics, specializing in Monetary Economics, supervised by Professor
    Pedro Bação and Professor Ricardo Sousa and presented to the Faculty of Economics, University
    of Coimbra. \par}

    \vspace*{0.5cm}

    {\small September 2014 \par}

    \vspace*{1.1cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}

    \textsc{\small Faculty of Economics, University of Coimbra}
    \par
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage     %% imp
\restoregeometry     %% imp
%% cover.tex ends--------------------------
\Blinddocument       %% for demo
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I used it, but it works only separately.  If I use it in the full thesis compilation, it doesn't work... 
Please, could you see the codes for full compilation and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Gilson Soory, I don't have `dmathesis` for testing :)

Comment: Can you find it here? https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5xi8xr1vrqc1df/dmathesis.cls 

or is needed more than this file?

Comment: @Gilson I have updated the answer. Just check the page layout from second page onwards. I am not sure if I messed up.

Comment: Harish, thank you again. This last is the same than the first one. I'm compiling my thesis with separately chapters, using \include environment. So the cover page is made separately, and also all chapters, and the bibliography. So, I have to make the cover page separately and include it in the full thesis compilation. Could you see the compilation codes in the question? the second one.

Comment: @Gilson Save everything between `% cover page starts` and `% cover page ends` in the second code as `cover.tex` and you are good to go.

Comment: Harish, Thank you very much for your time. It is working perfectly. This last suggestion did not work, but I had changed the \documentclass to Book, and I could have it. The only problem is that in the cover page has the same format than inside of thesis, which make the space between line in 1.5, which in turn make the title with a lot of space as it is a bit long. anyway, the main problem is solved. thank you very much.

Comment: @Gilson Accepting the answer is how you thank here in this site. :) For details refer to: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)